# Is it possible to emulate 56k connection using two virtual machines?

Tags: modem

I have successfully emulated a direct serial connect with a windows client (Windows 2000) with a CentOS 8 dial-in server (mgetty+pppd) between two virtual machines (Windows 2000 is client and CentOS 8 is server), using libvirt in Slackware Host.

Now I want to emulate a old PPP connection with Linux client (Mandriva Linux) using kppp and the same CentOS 8 server.
I don't had any 56k modem, but I know a project exist to emulate a modem and is called [tcpser](https://github.com/FozzTexx/tcpser), with Windows doesn’t work because the serial port is busy by the tcpser program, so I use Mandriva, on Mandriva I run the tcpser program:

```
tcpser -d /dev/ttyS0 -n"010010101"
```

On Centos I run the tcpser program

```
tcpser -d /dev/ttyS0 -n"010010102"
```

Using kppp and doing "modem interrogation" report all ok(I'm checking with minicom on Centos)..but result strings are all empty.

When I try to connect from Mandriva to number the modem is stuck at the initialization string as you can see from this minicom output and and doesn’t create the connection:

```
OK

OK
+++ATH

OK

OK
ATZ
```

The two virtual machines are connected directly by a fake serial (socket) one is bind and the other is connect
Those are the XML’s of serial of the machines.

Mandriva

```
<serial type="unix">
  <source mode="connect" path="/tmp/ppp.sock"/>
  <target type="isa-serial" port="0">
    <model name="isa-serial"/>
  </target>
  <alias name="serial0"/>
</serial>
```

CentOS

```
<serial type="unix">
  <source mode="bind" path="/tmp/ppp.sock"/>
  <target type="isa-serial" port="0">
    <model name="isa-serial"/>
  </target>
  <alias name="serial0"/>
</serial>
```

**UPDATE 1**: Some progress, tcpser simply make a “bridge” from a serial to a TCP application, in my case is impossible to make a bridge from serial to mgetty (is not TCP, it use serial line), but is possible to make a bridge from serial to telnet:

```
tcpser -d /dev/ttyS1 -s 38400 -l 7 -tsSiI -i "s0=1" -n"010010102=centos.domain.private:23"
```

I have tried the HyperTerminal from Windows client and works fine, I can login as the old good ptsn-modem way.

Unfortunately the PPP connection fail with "loopback error" "loopback detected" error 17 in both Mandriva and Windows client

PSL I know Windows 2000, Mandriva Linux are not supported and they are security risk, but is only testing.

Comment: I really don’t think I would embark on doing something like this, but this is a really fun Q&A post. Great work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found using this very good [“how to” blog post](https://blog.dandart.co.uk/2018/07/retro-dial-up-network-fun.html), I have only changed some options of PPP to use pap authentication.

I have tried to connect from Windows and Mandriva and works fine, using a fake or empty password deny login (login options of PPP)
A good "plus" will be to connect a real serial modem to the fake "tnt" lines if only to hear the nice sound of the connection handshake.

`/etc/ppp/options`

```
lock
auth
login
```

`/etc/ppp/options.tnt3`

```
asyncmap 0 
crtscts 
local 
silent 
192.168.100.1:192.168.100.100
require-pap
115200
```

`/etc/ppp/pap-secrets`

```
# Secrets for authentication using PAP
#
# client    server           secret     IP addresses
*           *             ""            192.168.1.100
```

Finally I launch the PPP daemon with these simple arguments

```
pppd /dev/tnt3 nodetach persist
```